# MS Word: Can't Save Any File

Tags: microsoft-word, troubleshooting, microsoft-word-2013

I have Ms Office 2013 Professional, and Word don't let me save any file.

It says to check the **file block settings**, and i did, and there was nothing wrong there. 
I also checked the temp variable, and everything is in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get the error message in Office that a file is blocked by registry policy settings, you can do [following steps](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922850/en-us) to unlock the file:

Change the File Block settings to disable the restriction of certain file types:

- Click File > Options.
- If you cannot open a file in Office 2013 or Office 2010, open a blank document to start the Office application. For example, if you cannot open a Word file, open a new document in Word 2013 or Word 2010 to see the option.
- In the **Options** window, click **Trust Center** > Trust Center Settings.
- In the Trust Center window, click **File Block Settings**, and then clear the "Open" or "Save" check box for the file type that you want to open or save.
- Note Clear the option means allow user to open or save the file. Check the option means block the file.
- Click OK two times.
- Try to open or save the file that was blocked again.

[image]

Comment: It worked. I got confused and thought that if the box is checked it meant that word can open and/or save that file type.